# Tags needed for [dict-comprehension], [set-comprehension]? Scala [for-comprehension] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

List-, dict- and set-comprehensions are features in several languages, and the existing tags [list-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list-comprehension),[for-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for-comprehension) are mentioned below.

It seems there is an additional **need for new tags [dict-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dict-comprehension)** and **[set-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set-comprehension)**. These are not language-specific (to Python), although much of the usage is from Python. As a justification why these tags are needed:

- [[python] "dict comprehension"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%22dict+comprehension%22) currently has 1598 hits

  - **Recommendation 1: create [dict-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dict-comprehension)** (language-independent)
- [[python] "set comprehension"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%22set+comprehension%22) currently has 354 hits

  - **Recommendation 2: create [set-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set-comprehension)**

Related context:

- existing tag [list-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list-comprehension) has Python: 10.3K, Haskell: 1127, Erlang: 125, Ruby: 41, [C#]: 12
- existing tag [for-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for-comprehension) with 254 Scala questions.
- **Question 3:**

  - [list-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list-comprehension) currently defines [comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comprehension) as a synonym. That might have been ok for the majority of cases and before dict- and set-comprehensions were introduced, but what now? Should we leave it aliased? Or unalias [comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comprehension) and give it a definition which points to  [list-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list-comprehension), [dict-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dict-comprehension), [set-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/set-comprehension)?
- **Question 4:**

  - Does Scala call this concept sequence-comprehension, list-comprehension or for-comprehension? (see [Is there a Scala equivalent to Python's list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355768/is-there-a-scala-equivalent-to-pythons-list-comprehension))
  - Do Scala people see any need for defining a tag alias (to the more general tag [list-comprehension])? or else reciprocally mentioning [list-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list-comprehension) from [for-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/for-comprehension)?

and some language history:

- Python introduced list-comprehensions back in 2.0 [[PEP 202]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) in the year 2000
- Python introduced dict- and set-comprehensions in 2.7,3.0 [[PEP 274]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)
- see also https://sopython.com/wiki/In_which_Python_version_was_feature_X_introduced%3F

Comment: Scala's `for-comprehension` isn't an exact equivalent of python's `list/dict-comprehension`. The exact and only term used for Scala's `for-comprehension` is `for-comprehension`. In addition, there aren't `dict/list/set-comprehension`in Scala.

Comment: @XavierGuihot: that's not strictly true; the term [sequence-comprehension](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/111) is also used (less)? And to downvoters in general, please leave a constructive criticism or answer. I did some work to improve tag organization, and a bunch of driveby downvotes does not advance us in any way.

Comment: And I never suggested Scala's `for-comprehension` was related to `dict-comprehension`. Only possibly to `list-comprehension`. It would help if you explained (in an answer) why Scala's `for-comprehension`is different from a list-comprehension. I had already read related answers on SO and they're too vague or just Scala jargon for the rest of us.

Comment: You're right, as part of `for-comprehension`s are `sequence-comprehension`s (in my experience, the last term is rarely used) `for (a <- List(1,4,5)) yield 2*a` => `List(2,8,10)`. But you'd usually only use these for nested things: `for (a <- List(1,4,5); b <- List(3,4); if b == 4) yield a*b`. for-comprehensions are often enjoyed with monads: `for (a <- Some(4); b <- Some(3)) yield a*b // Some(12)` which would be `None` if `b` was `None`. And yes distance is short between Monads and Seqs (`Some(2).toList // List(2)`). That might be a question for Scala gurus on SO ;p. And I haven't voted yet ;p

Comment: @XavierGuihot: neat, can you post that as a (partial) answer?

Comment: Also, don't assume us non-Scala people know Scala jargon, it helps to explain in language-neutral terms. A monad is an-object-wrapping-an-object, but I don't see that matters too much in this context; which types of comprehensions are used on which objects? And I can't understand what you meant by `Some(2).toList // List(2)`.